# How to know which formulae were recovered / corrupted in an Excel file

Tags: node.js, excel, spreadjs

I have a program which generates an Excel file. Specifically, it's a node app which generates a JSON file which is loaded into GrapeCity's SpreadJS and exported again via their ExcelIO libs. This file has a lot of formulae in it - at least a thousand of various forms built according to various rules from an input data set which is itself non-trivial. Whilst these files load file in SpreadJS and export in such a way that they load in Excel and appear to work, I get a number of errors from Excel when I try to load it:

```
Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.

Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part
Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part
Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part
```

After I initially posted this question, I eventually figured out that this was because the formulae in question were using single quotes for text strings rather than double. The question is - without playing guessing games, how could I identify **which** formulae Excel has removed / fixed? Excel's so-called log file is just a repetition of the equally unhelpful references.

Any of the following would count as good answers:

- A way to get Excel to tell me the string of the formula which it has a problem with
- A way to get Excel to tell me the cell reference (e.g. F5) of the formula which it has a problem with
- An external tool which would do the same
- A library or tool for validating Excel formulae which I could run on either the Excel file or the original input which would give me similar output. If it was an npm lib that would be even better

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/LesterLyu/fast-formula-parser/ works for verifying formulae.